# Использование юникода в консоли

Tags: c++, windows

Работаю MS VS 201, Win 7. Следующий код выводит не тот символ, какой надо:

```
system("chcp 65001");

std::cout << "\x00FF" << std::endl;
```

В чем проблема? Консоль не дружит с юникодом даже после смены codepage-а?

Comment: Вывелось ` FF`?

Comment: @gil9red нет, квадратик

Comment: А если так `std::cout << L"\u00FF" << std::endl;`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: MS VS 201 - похоже одна цифра потерялась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, консоль Windows дружит с юникодом без необходимости задавать кодовую страницу. В этом легко убедиться, запустив такой код:

```
HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
wchar_t str[]=L"\x00FF\n";
WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle,str,wcslen(str),NULL,NULL);
```

Однако, это не решает проблему, так как это работает **только** с консолью. Если стандартный вывод перенаправлен в файл, все нарушается. Можно перейти с WriteConsole на WriteFile, но это не очень удобно.

Если нужно именно UTF-8, в VS 2015+ работает так:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);    
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 1000);

    std::cout << u8"\x00FF" << std::endl;
}
```

Более традиционный способ, поддерживаемый VS2010+,  это все же использовать промежуточно широкие символы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout),  _O_U8TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"\x00FF" << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед запуском убедитесь что шрифт в консоли поддерживает данный символ.

```
#include <io.h> 
#include <iostream> //debug
#include <fcntl.h>
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"\x00FF" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```